# Unable to mock a method which takes an interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I have a service in my Spring Boot Project in which i have method which takes an interface.

```
interface IT {}
class AService {
 public String method(IT it) {}
}
```

I have two classes which implements that interface.

```
class AIT implements IT {}
class BIT implements IT {}
```

I am using this service method in some other service passing the AIT/BIT class object according to my need.

Now, I am writing the test cases for other service mocking the Service

```
public class OtherServiceTests {

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

  
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    // none of these mocks working
        Mockito.when(service.method(Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn("");
    Mockito.when(service.method(Mockito.any(IT.class)))
                .thenReturn("");
    Mockito.when(service.method(Mockito.any(BIT.class)))
                .thenReturn("");
    Mockito.when(service.method(Mockito.any(AIT.class)))
                .thenReturn("");
    // all returing to NullPointerException

    
        otherService = new OtherSerice();
    }

}
```

None of these mocks are working for this method only. Other mocks are working fine. It is returning NullPointerException which makes the tests fail.

I am new to testing using mockito. If anyone can guide me for this solution than this will be very helpful for me.

Comment: does it fail for "IT.class" only, or for all three? it's natural for "IT.class" to fail since it doesn't have any methods inside

Comment: It is failing for all

Comment: You are creating a new `OtherService` which probably uses it, which leads to not being able to inject it into that instance. Looks like you are mixing a lot of things up without understanding what you are actually doing. Mixing Spring Boot things with mocking, while you probably don't need the Spring Boot stuff.

Comment: I strongly recommend using [spock](http://spockframework.org) for all your testing. It is spring boot friendly and provides super simple, easy and powerful mocking. IMHO once you've used it you'll never use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Mock is not initialized and the annotation `@MockBean` should be replaced with `@Mock`.
Try to change it like this:

```
public class AServiceTest {
    @Mock
    AService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Mockito.when(service.method(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("");
        assertEquals("", service.method(new AIT()));
    }
}
```